# What is the name for a person who raises turkeys?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, professions

Some agricultural professions have specific names assigned to them. For example, a person who raises sheep is a *shepherd* and a person who raises cattle is a *rancher*. What would a person who raises turkey (or perhaps poultry in general) be called?

Comment: A turkey farmer.

Comment: @PeterShor Are you sure? Don’t farmers raise vegetables and dairy products, and ranchers raise animal flesh for meat? For example, it is an ostrich ranch, etc. [These people](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_difference_between_a_ranch_and_a_farm) seem to think so, and so do [these](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070612051553AA9QRYn). There seems to be some [historical trending](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sheep+ranch%2Csheep+farm&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) going on here. Maybe it only applies to the American West.

Comment: Peter Shor is right: turkey farmer, chicken farmer, pig farmer, etc.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shepherd or sheepherder, is a person who tends, feeds, or guards flocks of sheep. Not necessarily the owner/breeder

Comment: In the UK, it's also fairly common to hear "poultry farmer".

Comment: A person who raises cattle is a *cowherd*, in direct analogy to *shepherd*, *goatherd*, etc. A *rancher* is someone who owns a ranch, a very large open-range livestock farm. It could be a cattle ranch, or a sheep ranch (common in Australia / New Zealand, where ranches are called *stations*) or even a ranch for some more exotic species, such as alpaca or ostrich.

Comment: i'd probably go with turkey **rancher** rather than farmer. there's also "turkey breeder" as mentioned below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The word you are looking for is  ***poulterer*** (there is an obsolete version, ***poulter***), or perhaps ***poulteress***.  All are found in the OED in this sense.

Comment: "Do you know the Poulterer's, in the next street but one, at the corner?" Scrooge inquired.

"I should hope I did," replied the lad.

"An intelligent boy!" said Scrooge.  "A remarkable boy! Do you know whether they"ve sold the prize Turkey that was hanging up there -- Not the little prize Turkey: the big one?"

Comment: Looking at the hits in [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=poultryman%2Cpoulterer%2Cchicken+farmer%2Cpoultry+raiser&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), it seems that the usage over the last century or so is that a *poulterer* is somebody who sells poultry (like a *butcher* is somebody who sells meat), and a *poultryman* is somebody who raises poultry (like a *rancher* is somebody who raises cattle). Earlier, there must have been some other term for *poultryman*. Maybe *poulterer* did double duty.

Comment: @PeterShor The OED has a quote about a poulter as someone who raised poultry, not just who sold it, but it is from a long time ago.

Comment: I would say poulterer is a seller of poultry. In Holland we even still have the Dutch translation of the word on the shops:  Poelier

Comment: I have a friend who raises turkeys, so I asked him this question today. First word out of his mouth was _poulterer_; when I asked about _turkey farmer_, he said, "Yeah, you could call it that, too."

Comment: @J.R. Well if that’s not straight from the turkey’s mouth, I dunno what is! :) Thanks for the field work.

Comment: And if there are several of them they are poltergeis.

Answer (score 6):

In Australia, the general term, depending on the level of involvement, would be Turkey breeder or Turkey producer.

Answer (score 2):

[Poult](http://albc-usa.org/EducationalResources/vocabulary.html) (The American Livestock Breeds Conservancy)
"is a young domestic (not wild) turkey."
"Poultry are domesticated birds that are kept for meat or eggs including birds of the order Galliformes:  chicken, turkey, natatorial (swimming) birds: duck and goose."

[Poultry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_animal_names#Terms_by_species_or_taxon) (Wikipedia)

If you want to be technically specific, it would be ***poulter***.
Informally, you can say ***turkey farmer***.

See also:
[poultry](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/poultry) (dictionary.reference.com)
mid-14c., from O.Fr. pouletrie "domestic fowl" (late 13c.), from poulet "young fowl" (see pullet). Poulterer (1630s) is a redundancy, but has largely ousted original poulter (c.1400), from O.Fr. pouletier "poulterer," with agent suffix -er. Poetic poulter's measure (1570s) is of fanciful origin.

Answer (score 0):

Aviculterer or aviculturist for breeder or keeper of birds.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please [edit] to add [citations to reliable sources](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) that support the assertions made here.